# trying to replace an item in a list, but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, list

I just started to build my own hangman game.
My problem is as follows though:

I choose a random noun as the solution and create a list with "_" as long as the noun is.

When a user enters a correct letter I want to replace every underscore matching with that letter.

It seems that I'm able to get the index of that letter but it does not replace it within the "_" list.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# preset for words to be guessed
random_nouns = ["brick", "servant", "pan", "vest", "bead", "end", "stocking", "lettuce", "flag", "wash", "sea", "ice",
                "amount", "fruit", "train", "railway", "dolls", "stitch",
                "bone", "shame", "step", "smell", "error", "stone", "theory", "cows", "shape", "apparatus",
                "representative", "crown", "wish", "space", "calculator", "actor",
                "beginner"]
solution = random_nouns[random.randint(1, len(random_nouns))]
# split word in characters and add it to a list so the guessed letters can be matched
solution_chars = list(solution)
solution_as_underscore = list("_ " * len(solution_chars))
solution_as_underscore_string = "".join(solution_as_underscore)
print(solution)
# print(solution_chars)

# to check if input is not numerical and only alphabetical
numerals = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
number_of_chars = len(solution)
solution_try = []
right_letter_index = 0
count = 0

while count < len(solution):
    print(solution_as_underscore_string, "\n")
    print(solution_chars)
    guessed_letter = input("Try a letter! ").lower()
    if len(guessed_letter) > 1:
        print("Invalid input, please only enter one letter a time.")
        quit()
    elif guessed_letter not in solution:
        pass
    # TODO: build hangman
    elif guessed_letter in solution:
        for letter in solution_chars:
            if letter == guessed_letter:
                index = solution_chars.index(letter)
                print(index)
                print("That was correct.\n")
                solution_as_underscore[index] = guessed_letter
    count += 1

if count >= number_of_chars and solution_as_underscore != solution_chars:
    print("\nYou lost.")
    quit()
```

Also is my code understandable? I'm not sure if im coding the right way.

Comment: Have you tried printing `solution_as_underscore` to see if it contains what you expect?

Comment: `index = solution_chars.index(letter)` won't do the right thing if there are duplicate letters. It returns the index of the first match, you'll never get the indexes of the duplicates.

Comment: You should use `enumerate()` to get the index and character at the same time, rather than calling `index()`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much! I'll try to get it to work with enumerate()

Comment: unrelated - but I would shift this range down 1 `solution = random_nouns[random.randint(1, len(random_nouns))]` as the randint will never return 0 i.e 'brick' or the first element of random_nouns. Also it might return 35 i.e. throwing index out of range. Python list indices start with 0 and ends with n-1. so `randint` parameters should be `(0, len(random_nouns) - 1)`

Comment: I suspect `solution_as_underscore = list("_ " * len(solution_chars))` is not doing what you want. That's why I told you to print that variable to see if contains the expected values.

Comment: Normally in hangman, only failed guesses count against the guessing limit.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you need to write frollowing line of code in `elif` part

```
solution_as_underscore_string = " ".join(solution_as_underscore)
```

try this,

```
  elif guessed_letter in solution:
        for letter in solution_chars:
            if letter == guessed_letter:
                index = solution_chars.index(letter)
                #print(index)
                print("That was correct.\n")
                solution_as_underscore[index] = guessed_letter
                solution_as_underscore_string = " ".join(solution_as_underscore)
                print('solution',solution)
    count += 1
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much! Now I Just need to get it to work for multiple letters in a word..

Comment: What if there are repeated words in the string like calculator? That will mess up. Your current code only works if there are not repeated letters

Comment: design could be implemented with just strings & using `str.replace()` (getting the repeated chars for free) pseudo code would be something lke: assign answer to string, assign current_state to string; accept user input, current_state.replace("_", user_input) then check for winning condition, if current_state == answer: win, else repeat process. Now if you're doing this as a learning exercise in data structures obviously you'd want to stick to working it out with lists (which might be happening under the hood with str.replace()): https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, basically replace the last part of your code with this.

```
numerals = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
number_of_chars = len(solution)
solution_try = []
right_letter_index = 0
count = 0
all_indexes=[]
while count < len(solution):
    solution_as_underscore=[x for x in solution_as_underscore if x!=" "]
    print(solution_as_underscore)
    print(solution_chars)
    guessed_letter = input("Try a letter! ").lower()
    
    
    if len(guessed_letter) > 1:
        print("Invalid input, please only enter one letter a time.")
        
    elif guessed_letter not in solution:
        pass
    
    elif guessed_letter in solution_chars:
        for fum,letter in enumerate(solution_chars):
            if letter == guessed_letter:
                for i in range(0, len(solution_chars)) : 
                    if solution_chars[i] == guessed_letter : #=== Is the letter at that index position same
                        
                        solution_as_underscore[i] = guessed_letter #=== Replace the letter
                print("That was correct.\n")
                print(''.join(solution_as_underscore))
                if solution_as_underscore==solution_chars:
                    print("You won!")
                    quit()
                break
                
    count += 1

if count >= number_of_chars and solution_as_underscore != solution_chars:
    print("\nYou lost.")
    quit()
```

Sample output 1

```
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! s
That was correct.

s_______
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! d
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! o
That was correct.

s_o_____
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! c
That was correct.

s_oc____
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! k
That was correct.

s_ock___
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! i
That was correct.

s_ocki__
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! n
That was correct.

s_ockin_
['s', 't', 'o', 'c', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
Try a letter! g
That was correct.

s_ocking

You lost.
```

Sample Output 2:

```
['s', 't', 'i', 't', 'c', 'h']
Try a letter! s
That was correct.

s_____
['s', 't', 'i', 't', 'c', 'h']
Try a letter! t
That was correct.

st_t__
['s', 't', 'i', 't', 'c', 'h']
Try a letter! i
That was correct.

stit__
['s', 't', 'i', 't', 'c', 'h']
Try a letter! c
That was correct.

stitc_
['s', 't', 'i', 't', 'c', 'h']
Try a letter! h
That was correct.

stitch
You won!
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Hangman, you do not get penalized for correct guesses.The limit is on the number of incorrect guesses (which is why players don't like short words; fewer correct characters to land on).

I have added here `fail_limit` and swapped `fail_count` for `count`, incremented only in the wrong-guess branch, so that this rule is observed.

As suggested in comments, you need to step through the word and update every instance of the guessed letter, so using `enumerate` is a good option to retain the index of the letter you're checking.

The `solution_attempt` is initialized with underscores (not underscore-plus-space strings) and updated as the game progresses, hence the change of name - it only *starts* as underscores.

One further thing you probably need to decide about is what to do when the user guesses a letter that has already been guessed (and how to detect this).

```
import random

# preset for words to be guessed
random_nouns = ["brick", "servant", "pan", "vest", "bead", "end", "stocking", "lettuce", "flag", "wash", "sea", "ice",
                "amount", "fruit", "train", "railway", "dolls", "stitch",
                "bone", "shame", "step", "smell", "error", "stone", "theory", "cows", "shape", "apparatus",
                "representative", "crown", "wish", "space", "calculator", "actor",
                "beginner"]
fail_limit = 5
solution = random_nouns[random.randint(1, len(random_nouns))]
# split word in characters and add it to a list so the guessed letters can be matched
solution_chars = list(solution)
solution_attempt = list("_" * len(solution_chars))
print(solution) ### for debug checking
# print(solution_chars)

# to check if input is not numerical and only alphabetical
numerals = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
number_of_chars = len(solution)
solution_try = []
right_letter_index = 0
fail_count = 0

while fail_count < fail_limit and "_" in solution_attempt:
    print(" ".join(solution_attempt), "\n")
    guessed_letter = input("Try a letter! ").lower()
    if len(guessed_letter) > 1:
        print("Invalid input, please only enter one letter a time.")
        quit()
    elif guessed_letter not in solution:
        print("Wrong guess")
        fail_count += 1
    # TODO: build hangman
    elif guessed_letter in solution:
        print("That was correct.\n")
        for lx, letter in enumerate(solution_chars):
            if letter == guessed_letter:
                solution_attempt[lx] = guessed_letter

if "_" in solution_attempt:
    print("\nYou lost.")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it:", solution)
```